# How to Override createUser() ASP .NET Membership method to display custom error message?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

How to Override createUser() Membership method to display custom error message when password check fails??

**I Used the Web Site Administration Tool, which provides a wizard-like interface for creating new users. (To start this tool, click ASP.NET Configuration on the Website menu in the Microsoft Visual Studio)**


Web.Config file:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="BlueDDApp.Controllers.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="8"  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])$"  passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Custom Membership class::

```
    public class MyMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public MyMembershipProvider()
    {
        //Membership.ValidatingPassword += new MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler(OnValidatePassword);
        ValidatingPassword += ValidatePassword;

    }
   /* public override MembershipUser CreateUser( string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        ValidatingPassword += ValidatePassword;

        return base.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey, out status);
    }*/
    void ValidatePassword(object sender, ValidatePasswordEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex check = new Regex("^(?i)(?!.*" + e.UserName + ").*$");
        if (!check.IsMatch(e.Password))
        {
            e.FailureInformation = new HttpException("blah blah");
            e.Cancel = true;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the _Web Site Administration Tool_ is relevant since a custom error message makes only sense if you provide a custom user-administration.

Comment: Hmm ok, never thought to use it productively. But have a look here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx and here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053007-1.aspx. Maybe you can rollout your custom Web Site Administration Tool.

Comment: Ok Tim i think it make some sense.

Comment: No Tim i don't need it now. Now what i think is to work with some custom model and view to register a user (create) and use membership service to register a user. If you have relevant example link then please do share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp:CreateUserWizard control, which I presume you are ( it will connect to a membership provider from your web.config ), then :

In Design mode, if you click on this control, in the top right corner you have an icon, sort of an arrow, and there you can choose "Customize Create User Step" option. This will transform the control, expanding it into a separate controls that are used inside. Now you can access error message ( Literal control ) and change it to display static message, or display dynamically changing messages from code.

You can also add events to the CreateUserWizard like CreatingUser, CreateUserError and CreatedUser which will let you customize the behavior and how the creation is being used even more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great sample about custom MembershipUser:

[Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx)